# PHP array show list with just values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the output of below when i do

> print_r($images);

Is it possible to list the values without [0] etc

```
Array ( [0] => 225403a4491411e2b4f022000a1f9ac6_7.jpg 
[1] => 62605578491011e2815722000a1fa518_7.jpg 
[2] => 0b5c9316490d11e283e822000a1f8e5b_7.jpg )
```

Comment: http://php.net/foreach - what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to loop the array and echo each value :

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image;
}
```

`print_r` prints information about a variable - Not its value;

Comment: I often forget you can skip the `$k => $v` and just go straight to the point! :)

Answer (score 7):

It most certainly is yes!

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++)
{
    echo $images[$i] . "\n";
}
```

or even

```
echo implode("\n", $images);
```

and as suggested

```
foreach ($images as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

Have a browse through these handy pages

http://php.net/for,
http://php.net/foreach,
http://php.net/implode

Comment: A foreach() would be shorter. Plus, doing a count() on a for condition is a performance killer.

Comment: If using a loop, I'd use foreach instead of for in this case. `foreach($images as $image) { echo $image.PHP_EOL; }`

Comment: I think a foreach would be tidier here but + 1 for implode.

Comment: I will add a foreach, @EdsonMedina a for even with a count is always faster than a foreach

Comment: `foreach` generally are slower than `for` but they are most certainly easier to read :) Good edit.

Comment: You know the condition will be executed on every step, right? So if the array has a million records, you will do count() a million times.

Comment: @EdsonMedina Yes we know, still quicker though, no secret array copying going on :)

Comment: @webnoob: Wrong. Just wrong. Both technically and also from the conception to say so at this place. Just wrong.

Comment: @Dale: Wrong. Just wrong. There is no secret array copying going on. Just wrong.

Comment: @hakre I believe (though could be wrong) that unless a reference is passed foreach uses a copy of the array?

Comment: @hakre - I lost the actual point of your comments in the "just wrong" spam ... Edit: See the comment below.

Comment: @dale - See this post. You are correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413249/why-is-foreach-so-slow so the better option would be to calculate the size of the for loop before looping and then use that number to avoid `count` on each iteration.

Comment: @EdsonMedina - If you calculate the size of the array first in line with my comments above then it should work out faster.

Comment: @EdsonMedina I'm not interested any more, and we were originally discussing an array with 1 million indices, I see you had to up to the ante 3x ;)

Comment: @webnoob: You should better learn to run your own metrics and actually as you refer to that (bad made resource), **read:** *"Conclusion:
In all cases I've found that the foreach loop is substantially faster than both the while() and for() loop procedures."* - But anyway, don't just blindly refer to metrics here. If you're in the realm where you're having to worry about function call overhead, you're probably also in the realm where you need to reevaluate all data structures and algorithms used.

Comment: @Dale: Yes and no. It's not that easy. Generally, don't worry about all that, PHP takes care of it pretty well. BTW, even if foreach uses a copy - so what? Do you think that means it's expensive? Really? PHP generally uses copy on write, so a copy is not expensive at all.

Comment: It's all very interesting but not worth this extended chat

Comment: @hakre feel free to post your own answer

Comment: @Dale: Other questions about particular points exist, e.g. [php foreach, why using pass by reference of a array is fast?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7786580/367456) - take care of the calling context, e.g. here *inside a function*.

Comment: @Dale: Please make yourself comfortable how this site works, esp. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: @hakre - Another post from a few hours ago suggests that foreach is slower again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929468/php-for-loop-vs-foreach-with-range). Whilst I appreciate that running my own tests is the best option, they can't all be wrong ... I agree the speed won't matter at all but they do seem to be slower. p.s Do you have a resource you can share about them being faster?

Comment: @webnoob: The speed *heavily* depends on context. You can not run some bogus metric isolated upfront and then draw conclusions from it. That would be a major flaw and conceptually broken. Don't do it.

Comment: @hakre - Ok I guess that makes sense. If we needed to optimise it down to that level then it should be done inline with the data it's processing. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @webnoob: Exactly. And only if you spotted a bottleneck at that place already. That is why `foreach` should be preferred: It's easy to use, it has very good performance and you can iterate over more than just arrays with it. These things are often much more important than bare-metal performance.